# C++ Derived Class problems

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am making a game in C++ and am having problems with my derived class.  I have a base class called GameScreen which has a vitrual void draw() function with no statements.  I also have a derived class called MenuScreen which also has a virtual void draw() function and a derived class from MenuScreen called TestMenu which also has a void draw() function.  In my program I have a list of GameScreens that I have a GameScreen iterator pass through calling each GameScreens draw() function.

The issue is that I have placed a TestMenu object on the GameScreen list.  Instead of the iterator calling the draw() function of TestMenu it is calling the draw() function of the GameScreen class.  Does anyone know how I could call the draw() function of TestMenu instead of the one in GameScreen.

Here is the function:

```
// Tell each screen to draw itself.
//gsElement is a GameScreen iterator
    //gsScreens is a list of type GameScreen
void Draw()
{
    for (gsElement = gsScreens.begin(); gsElement != gsScreens.end(); gsElement++)
    {
        /*if (gsElement->ssState == Hidden)
            continue;*/

        gsElement->Draw();
    }
}
```

Here are a copy of my classes:

```
class GameScreen {
public:
    string strName;
    bool bIsPopup;
    bool bOtherScreenHasFocus;
    ScreenState ssState;
    //ScreenManager smScreenManager;

    GameScreen(string strName){
        this->strName = strName;
    }

    //Determine if the screen should be drawn or not
    bool IsActive(){
        return !bOtherScreenHasFocus && 
            (ssState == Active);
    }

    //------------------------------------
    //Load graphics content for the screen
    //------------------------------------
    virtual void LoadContent(){
    }

    //------------------------------------
    //Unload content for the screen
    //------------------------------------
    virtual void UnloadContent(){
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Update changes whether the screen should be updated or not and sets
    //whether the screen should be drawn or not.
    //
    //Input:
    //  bOtherScreenHasFocus - is used set whether the screen should update
    //  bCoveredByOtherScreen - is used to set whether the screen is drawn or not
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    virtual void Update(bool bOtherScreenHasFocus, bool bCoveredByOtherScreen){
        this->bOtherScreenHasFocus = bOtherScreenHasFocus;

        //if the screen is covered by another than change the screen state to hidden
        //else set the screen state to active
        if(bCoveredByOtherScreen){
            ssState = Hidden;
        }
        else{
            ssState = Active;
        }
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    //Takes input from the mouse and calls appropriate actions
    //-----------------------------------------------------------
    virtual void HandleInput(){
    }

    //----------------------
    //Draw content on screen
    //----------------------
    virtual void Draw(){
    }

    //--------------------------------------
    //Deletes screen from the screen manager
    //--------------------------------------
    void ExitScreen(){
        //smScreenManager.RemoveScreen(*this);
    }
};

class MenuScreen: public GameScreen{
public:
    vector <BUTTON> vbtnMenuEntries; 

    MenuScreen(string strName):GameScreen(strName){
    }

    virtual void Update(bool bOtherScreenHasFocus, bool bCoveredByOtherScreen){
        GameScreen::Update(bOtherScreenHasFocus, bCoveredByOtherScreen);

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vbtnMenuEntries.size(); i++){
            vbtnMenuEntries[i].IsPressed();
        }
    }

    virtual void Draw(){
        GameScreen::Draw();

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vbtnMenuEntries.size(); i++)
            vbtnMenuEntries[i].Draw();
    }

};

class testMenu : public MenuScreen{
public:
    vector<OBJECT> test;
    //OBJECT background3();
//  OBJECT testPic(512, 384, buttonHover.png, 100, 40, 100, 40);
//  BUTTON x(256, 384, buttonNormal.png, buttonHover.png, buttonPressed.png, 100, 40, test());
    bool draw;

    testMenu():MenuScreen("testMenu"){
        OBJECT background3(1, 1, 0, TEXT("background.png"), 1, 1, 1024, 768);
        OBJECT testPic(512, 384,0, TEXT("buttonHover.png"), 1, 1, 100, 40);
        test.push_back(background3);
        test.push_back(testPic);
        //background3.Init(int xLoc, int yLoc, int zLoc, LPCTSTR filePath, int Rows, int Cols, int Width, int Height)
        //test.push_back(background3);
    //  vbtnMenuEntries.push_back(x);
        draw = false;
    }

    void Update(bool bOtherScreenHasFocus, bool bCoveredByOtherScreen){
        MenuScreen::Update(bOtherScreenHasFocus, bCoveredByOtherScreen);
        //cout << "X" << endl;
        /*if(MouseLButton == true){
            testMenu2 t;
            smManager.AddScreen(t);
        }*/
    }

    void Draw(){
        //background3.Draw();
        test[0].Draw();
        test[1].Draw();
        MenuScreen::Draw();
    ///*if(draw){*/
    //  testPic.Draw();
    //}
}

/*void test(){
    draw = true;
}*/

};
```

Comment: Curt's answer is correct.  You should make GameScreen's Draw function pure virtual so you *can't* have this type of error.

Answer (score 9):

If gsScreens is a list of objects instead of a list of pointers (as your code suggests), then you're not storing what you think you're storing in it.

What's happening is that -- instead of putting a TestMenu into the list, you're actually constructing a new MenuScreen using the compiler-generated copy constructor and putting this MenuScreen into the list.

C++ is polymorphic through pointers, so if you don't have a pointer you won't get polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Curts suggestion sounds correct change gsScreens to be a list of type GameScreen*.

Polymorphism requires pointers or references to objects.

Comment: Avoid such accidental copying by declaring the copy constructor and operator= private. This supresses the defaults, which are there for compatibility with C structs. If you want a class to be copyable (rare), then implement both. Make sure they interact correctly with the destructor.

Comment: C++ is also polymorphic through references.

Comment: That's an implementation detail ;) In the semantics of the language, references and pointers are different things and hence both should be mentioned when you talk about polymorphism. I'm not saying you're wrong, I was just adding to your almost correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

To get the polymorphic behavior you're after and at the same time use a `std::vector<>`, you must store *pointers* to the base class type in the vector, instead of storing *values*. Also, you must remember to free their memory before the vector goes out of scope.

For instance:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Base
{
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

struct Derived1 : public Base
{
    void Foo() { }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base
{
    void Foo() { }
};

struct delete_ptr
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(T& p)
    {
        delete p;
        p = 0;
    }
};

int wmain(int, wchar_t*[])
{
    std::vector<Base*> items;
    items.push_back(new Derived1);
    items.push_back(new Derived2);

    Base& first = items.front();
    first.Foo(); // Will boil down to Derived1::Foo().

    Base& last = items.back();
    last.Foo(); // Will boil down to Derived2::Foo().

    std::for_each(items.begin(), items.end(), delete_ptr())
};
```

Answer (score 0):

[Curt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88558/c-derived-class-problems#88620) is absolutely correct, but I'd just like to throw a little more information at it.

This problem (storing base-class objects, rather than pointers) is sometimes called "slicing".

Also, I tend to make use of the following macro:

```
#define DISALLOW_COPYING(X) \
    private: \
        X(const X &); \
        const X& operator= (const X& x)
```

Then you put this somewhere in your class definition:

```
class Foo {
    // ...
    DISALLOW_COPYING(Foo);
};
```

If another class attempts to copy the object, you'll get a compiler error (because the methods are declared private). If the class itself attempts to copy the object, you'll get a linker error (because the methods have no implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Boost (www.boost.org, a library I would recommend anyone coding in C++ use) provides a noncopyable base class that does exactly that; you don't need an ugly macro that way.